# PowerShell on Target Machines v2.* logs

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, continuous-integration, cicd

I am trying to execute on powershell script while deployment on a server SO i used Azure CI/CD task named "PowerShell on Target Machines v2.*"  but i am not getting any logs from that powershell script.

Do we have any command or way to receive all logs/output from powershell script executed on target server to CI/CD logging window.

Script is executing fine but whenever any error is thrown i  want that error message to be shown in CI/CD logs.

i have tried version 1 and then moved to version 2,  and under exception handling i had set Exit code 1 . but still  exception is not getting received in pipeline logs

Comment: I dont think, there is a direct way of viewing the logs from the CI/CD pipeline. You may need to copy the log the file in common path and process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same with you with task V2, you can use V3, it will show the  output/error.

[image]

My powershell script:

```
try {
    # Create a new directory
    New-Item -Path C:\Users\Test -Name NewDir -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
    # Display the error details
    Write-Host "An error occurred:" -ForegroundColor Red
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
    Write-Host $_.ErrorDetails.Message -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

In **V2** task, the output is below:
[image]

On **V3** task, the output is below:
[image]

**Edit:** The PowerShell on Target Machines task actually runs `enter-pssession` to connect to remote machine. If you are not able to run V3 task, you can use powershell task instead. Script sample below:

```
$username = 'username'
$password = 'password'
$computername = $(computernameorip)
$secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $password
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$secureString
$cred = [PSCredential]::New($username,$secureString)
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $(computernameorip) -Credential $cred

Enter-PSSession -Session $session
Invoke-Command -FilePath C:\test\test2.ps1 -Session $session
Exit-PSSession
```

[image]

Pipeline result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @wade, Thanks for  reply, i could only use  task V2. Could you please suggest a way for logging and break my rm task if any error  is thrown.

Comment: @Tech_dopamine, the `PowerShell on Target Machines` task actually runs `enter-pssession` to connect to remote machine. Hence, if you cannot use V3 task, you can use powershell task instead. I edited the reply with sample script and pipeline result, thanks.

Comment: HI @wade  Now i am getting this   ==>   Error: Unable to validate the given database "TESTDb" and server "TestServerName".
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.error "".    Basically via ps script i am trying to login into Biztalk server database.. although this is working fine if script is executed manually on server. but Via RM error is comming.

Comment: connection string is  like      $Catalog.ConnectionString = "SERVER= $dbServer;DATABASE=TESTDb;Integrated Security=SSPI"

Comment: The error could be caused by the servername cannot be reached, try to ping the server name check if it's ok. If not, you need to add hosts and refresh dns. But  it seems a  new query for your powershell script execution, not for the query on this ticket. If the current query is resolved, could you please help mark the answer? and you can raise a new ticket to share the ps script detail error and we can check further. Thanks.